# Android Beta testing testers in a community receives different versions

Tags: android, testing

I updated the existing apk with updated one in beta testing when I tried by copying the download link in my device I gets the updated build but another tester in same community gets the old version of app or Item not found message.

Answer (score 1):

To be a beta tester your testers must join the specified G+ testing community AND sign up to be a tester at the URL given in your Developer Console.

Testing link is https://play.google.com/apps/testing/(your.package.name)

They will then receive beta versions but it could be a couple of hours after publishing before the update is offered to your tester by Play Store.

Comment: testers already in the community and they tested first version successfully but after an update some tester gets the updated version but someone gets the old version of the same app by following the same link

Comment: Maybe the latest version is not applicable to their device.